# Shortcut to jump to random album in winamp?

Tags: winamp

I added lot of songs in the playlist and I want to listen to them in order (so, I would like to listen to one album after the other album). I have working prev / next global shortcuts.

But when I'm enough with listening to an album I would like to be able to jump to a random song of any other album just by pressing a single key (like the prev/next I have).

Any idea?

Comment: I found a similar question (actually it's the exact opposite, but we listen music the same way in fact). http://superuser.com/questions/346123/how-can-i-play-the-current-songs-album-in-winamp

Comment: You said you want to jump to a random song, then you said you want to play the albums in order. What exactly are you trying to do? Play each album in order, but have the songs shuffled within them? For example: `a1 a5 a3 a2 a4, b3 b1  b2, c7 c2 c3…`? Or do you want to play the songs of each album in order, but shuffle the albums as a whole? For example: `b1 b2 b3, c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7, a1 a2 a3 a4 a5…`?

Comment: He wants to be able to jump to a random album at any given time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can’t you just turn the random/shuffle function on? Then it will jump to a random song when you use Prev/Next.

Also, look in *Preferences->Global Hotkeys* and you can define your own hotkey(s) to jump to a random song and/or to toggle shuffle on/off.

If you want something fancier like normal-album,random-song or normal-song,random-album, then you’ll need a plugin like [Album Shuffle](http://www.winamp.com/plugin/album-shuffle-2-0/148018). There’s a couple of [request](http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=227732) [threads](http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=241878) where people have asked for various types of shuffle and a few options have been given.

Comment: Shuffle would not allow me to listen to the albums in order. I don't see any "jump to random song" in Preferences->Global Hotkeys

Comment: *> I'm enough with an album I would like to be able to jump to a random song. … Shuffle would not allow me to listen to the albums in order.*   I don’t know what you are looking for.

Comment: I want to play the playlist in its normal order, and have a shortcut to jump on random song. (kind of "shuffle on", "next", "shuffle off" macro)

Comment: Then you’ll have to use a plugin like the above.